# recyclerView with Kotlin in new class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

have created a recyclerView with Kotlin on mainActivity.

it works just fine.

I would like now to transfer my code to a new class Call that class from MainActivity and activate the recyclerView that way.

Called that class at mainActivity, but apperantly that is not enough…

```
var newClass: NewClass = NewClass()
```

How do I call a class with a `recyclerView` or how to activate it ?

Added the call for newClass. Would like to remove all of these lines.

Thank you

This is my code at onCreate:

```
enter code here

var newClass: NewClass = NewClass()


rowsList = ArrayList<RowFromModel>()
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
adapter = RowListAdapter(rowsList!!, this)

rowsListRv.layoutManager = layoutManager
rowsListRv.adapter = adapter

//load data
var model = TableViewModel()

var dataFromModel: ArrayList<String> = model.getData()
for (i in 0..dataFromModel.size - 1) {
    val rowFromModel = RowFromModel()
    rowFromModel.row = dataFromModel.get(i)
    rowsList!!.add(rowFromModel)
}

adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
enter code here
```

Comment: You can do it by passing the `recyclerView` to the `NewClass` instance as a parameter in the constructor and do the work in `NewClass`

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I am not sure I understand how to implement it.
This is my code at onCreate:
I would like to delete all of it from this class...

Comment: Be sure to add what code your working with by adding it to your question tags! Not always apparent. ;)

Comment: @angle you can edit the question and add the code there. Also, please add the android tag to the question :)

Comment: Thanks !!  :)  just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NewClass` need some way to know the `recyclerView` and the `Context` (or Activity) to work on, so they should be passed to the class. You can do so by doing the following

```
class NewClass (val recyclerView: RecyclerView, val context: Context) {

    val rowsList = ArrayList<RowFromModel>() 
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) 
    val adapter = RowListAdapter(rowsList, context)

    // load data
    var model = TableViewModel()

    var dataFromModel: ArrayList<String> = model.data 
    val rowFromModel = RowFromModel()

    init {
        // this will be called after the constructor is called
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager 
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter 

        for (i in 0..dataFromModel.size - 1) {
            val rowFromModel = RowFromModel()
            rowFromModel.row = dataFromModel[i]
            rowsList.add(rowFromModel)
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

and then in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`, you can do the following

```
var newClass: NewClass = NewClass(rowsListRv, this)
```

Hope this helps!